# #1093 - Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to update a field with multiplication and it shows error `#1093 - Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data`

This is my query

```
UPDATE `order_details` SET `price` = 
(SELECT (od.quantity * p.pricePerUnit) 
FROM order_details od join products p ON od.id_product = p.id_product 
WHERE dp.id_product = p.id_product)
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: is problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quite do that in MySQL.  The best approach is a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE order_details od JOIN
       products p
       ON od.id_product = p.id_product
    SET price = od.quantity * p.pricePerUnit;
```

Comment: @MuhammadIlhamFauzi mark this as anwered if this solved your problem.